# How to write script which reads log file and group the logs by keywords and count it per hour

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, devops, python-itertools

I have my log file data with INFO, WARNING, ERROR, OTHER(FATAL, DEBUG).

please look my edited logfile below

```
10:00:00 INFO    
10:00:00 INFO   
10:01:51 WARNING    
10:02:05 ERROR      
10:05:20 INFO 
10:06:01 WARNING
10:07:08 ERROR 
10:44:00 DEBUG  
10:51:01 FATAL
10:52:05 ERROR  
11:01:59 INFO  
11:08:01 WARNING  
11:59:05 ERROR 
12:02:00 INFO
12:09:01 WARNING 
12:18:05 ERROR 
12:31:00 INFO 
12:40:01 FATAL 
12:55:05 DEBUG 
13:05:36 INFO 
13:26:01 WARNING
13:30:05 ERROR
```

I need to count the total number of INFO, WARNING, ERROR, OTHER per hour.

OUTPUT should look like this below

```
10:00 3, 2,3,2 

11:00 1,1,1,0
```

10:00 in the output is time frame from 10:00:00 to 10:59:59

Imported pandas and itertools and used the groupby but couldn't get. I do not want to confuse you with my code.

EDit:
I am sorry, actually my logfiles contains one more filed with message
lof file looks like

```
10:00:00 INFO hi  
10:00:00 INFO hello
10:01:51 WARNING careful
10:02:05 ERROR failed
10:05:20 INFO hi
10:06:01 WARNING careful man
10:07:08 ERROR you failed
10:44:00 DEBUG do it again
10:51:01 FATAL dead
10:52:05 ERROR you have problem
11:01:59 INFO hello
11:08:01 WARNING careful
11:59:05 ERROR problem
12:02:00 INFO how are you
12:09:01 WARNING take care
12:18:05 ERROR problems
12:31:00 INFO good good
12:40:01 FATAL die
12:55:05 DEBUG about to die
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.  StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 2):

With your sample data:

```
df = pd.read_csv('logfile.log', sep='\s+', header=None)
df[0] = pd.to_datetime(df[0])
pd.crosstab(df[0].dt.hour, df[1])
```

Output:

```
1   DEBUG  ERROR  FATAL  INFO  WARNING
0                                     
10      1      3      1     3        2
11      0      1      0     1        1
12      1      1      1     2        1
13      0      1      0     1        1
```

---

Update: to have `OTHER`:

```
# read log file
df = pd.read_csv('logfile.log', header=None)

# extract the messages
df = df[0].str.extract('([\d:]+) (\w+)')

# convert to datetime
df[0] = pd.to_datetime(df[0])

df.loc[~df[1].isin(['INFO','WARNING','ERROR']), 1] = 'OTHER'
pd.crosstab(df[0].dt.hour, df[1])
```

Output:

```
1   ERROR  INFO  OTHER  WARNING
0                              
10      3     3      2        2
11      1     1      0        1
12      1     2      2        1
13      1     1      0        1
```

Comment: using `crosstab` is very elegant!

Comment: Hi, Your code is actually working but except info error warning I need debug, fatal or any other grouped as OTHER. Also can you see my edit to log file, thank you Quang.

Comment: Hi, I was really waiting for your reply but does this code work if I have one more column in my log file with messages. You see my edited log file also in my question. Can you check that please. Thank you.

Comment: Log file has three columns they are timestamp, message type and message. Before I only mentioned timestamp and message type. Can you check the edited logfile and help me with new script- Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Quang I have error "raise AttributeError("Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike " "values")
AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values"

Comment: Hi Quang, I am creating Docker image. I need to input the log file using stdin and exits by EOF and write the results to stdout. Could you make any changes according to that- Thanks.

Comment: Log file is around 100GB and space I have 10GB to validate. But anyway most important thing is to input the file using stdin, o/p stdout and exit by EOF, please update-Thank you.

Comment: I used the inpu=open() and output=(location, w) but how to use the EOF to exit the file or process

Answer (score 1):

You need:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
df.loc[df['type'].isin(['ERROR', 'INFO', 'WARNING']), 'type'] = 'OTHER'
df.groupby([df['time'].dt.hour, df['type']]).size().unstack().fillna(0)
```

Output:

```
type  DEBUG  FATAL  OTHER
time                     
10      1.0    1.0    8.0
11      0.0    0.0    3.0
12      1.0    1.0    4.0
13      0.0    0.0    3.0
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for help but except error info warning all other should be quoted as OTHER.

Answer (score 1):

Your df:

```
df

time     event
10:00:00 INFO    
10:00:00 INFO   
10:01:51 WARNING    
10:02:05 ERROR      
10:05:20 INFO 
10:06:01 WARNING
10:07:08 ERROR 
10:44:00 DEBUG  
10:51:01 FATAL
10:52:05 ERROR  
11:01:59 INFO  
11:08:01 WARNING  
11:59:05 ERROR 
12:02:00 INFO
12:09:01 WARNING 
12:18:05 ERROR 
12:31:00 INFO 
12:40:01 FATAL 
12:55:05 DEBUG 
13:05:36 INFO 
13:26:01 WARNING
13:30:05 ERROR
```

**you need to group according to the time and function of the event and use [DataFrame.Groupby.count](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html):**

```
df['time']=pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
count=df.groupby([df['time'].dt.hour,'event']).count().unstack()
print(count)

       time                         
event DEBUG ERROR FATAL INFO WARNING
time                                
10      1.0   3.0   1.0  3.0     2.0
11      NaN   1.0   NaN  1.0     1.0
12      1.0   1.0   1.0  2.0     1.0
13      NaN   1.0   NaN  1.0     1.0
```

---

```
count.columns=count.columns.droplevel()
count['OTHER']=count[['ERROR','INFO','WARNING']].sum(axis=1)
count=count[['DEBUG','FATAL','OTHER']].fillna(0)
print(count)


event  DEBUG  FATAL  OTHER
time                      
10       1.0    1.0    8.0
11       0.0    0.0    3.0
12       1.0    1.0    4.0
13       0.0    0.0    3.0
```

Comment: your column time data is 'time'? I show df of my solution

Comment: My log file has no column and row names. and I donot want any attributes to output also, because memory is critical. that is the requirment I have. Can you please post total code again with any necessary imports. my log file location is "D:/logfile.txt" -Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: then use 0 and 1 instead 'time' and 'event'

Comment: Actually I donot want any attributes to output also, because memory is critical. that is the requirment I have. Can you please post total code again with any necessary imports. my log file location is "D:/logfile.txt" -Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Hi, Actually my log file format is changed, can you please check my edit in my question once and can you please write any changes necessary to your code. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Without converting to date time:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('log_ex.txt', sep=' ', header=None, names=["time", "type"])
df['time'] = df['time'].apply(lambda x: x[:2])
df_new = pd.crosstab(df["time"], df["type"])


df_new["OTHER"] = df_new["FATAL"] + df_new["DEBUG"]
del df_new["FATAL"]
del df_new["DEBUG"]
```

Output:

```py
df_new 

type    ERROR   INFO    WARNING OTHER
time                
10  3   3   2   2
11  1   1   1   0
12  1   2   1   2
13  1   1   1   0
```

Comment: Thanks Julia but I got error below                                                                         
  df['time'] = df['time'].apply(lambda x: x[:2])
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable

Comment: ah I see! In my example, the first column was loaded as string so it worked. You could try casting it to string first and then it should work: `lambda x: str(x)[:2]`

Comment: I found no errors but I do not see any output either. Not really sure Why?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know. What's your working environment? I pasted your data into a file and ran the script in jupyter notebook and it worked.

Comment: I am using the PyCharm IDE. Can you post the output you got. -Thanks Julia

Comment: In Pycharm, you have to print the output to see something.

Comment: Hi Julia, Actually my log file format is changed, could you please check my edit in my question once and please write any changes necessary to your code. thank you.

Comment: the code still works the same and the output stays the same, even with the extra column because the additional column is dropped when applying `pd.crosstab`.

Comment: I am creating the docker image I have to input the log file using stdin and output file to stdout and exits by EOF. Can you update me, thank you Julia. Regards-Tony.